# Best strategy on a TikZ 3D figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

What would be the best strategy for producing this figure in TikZ?

[image: torus and cylinder]

To design it from the start in 3D with the data for the truncated torus and cylinder or to execute in 2D looking for the best ellipses and possible Bézier curves that fit? The intent is to show the two cross-sections are the same.

Comment: This is a stylized illustration. Trying to imitate it in actual 3d coordinates will have disappointing results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The example mostly uses 2D-coordinates for drawing. It is no 3D-drawing, therefore you have to look what needs to be drawn after/before the other elements.

I also made use of `\clip` to get overlays right, which is neccesary because `tikz` just draws on top of already drawn elements and has no support for visibility of 3D-objects.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,
                      background rectangle/.style={fill=black!60}, 
                      color=white,
                      very thick]

  \clip (-3,-1.5) rectangle (2,1.5);

    \begin{scope}[xshift=-1cm, yshift=.5cm]
        \draw [fill=black!70] (-1,0) ellipse (2cm and .5cm);
        \draw (0,0,0) arc (135:405:.71cm) -- cycle;
        \draw [fill=black!60] (-1,0) ellipse (1cm and .25cm);
        \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (1.5,-1);
        \draw (-1,-1) ellipse (2cm and .5cm);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}
        \draw [fill=black!70] (0,0,0) -- ++(1,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-4) -- ++(-1,0,0) -- cycle;
        \draw (1,-1,0) -- ++(0,0,-3);
        \draw [fill=black!50] (0,0,0) arc (135:405:.71cm) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should calculate the coordinates in 2D in other program and then just use `\draw` command in tikz to draw the figure with this coordinates.

If you plot it in 3D coordinated (tikz-3dplot) you will have problems to draw the arc in the right place.